# How to split a variable and store the result of the same in different variables in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have the following data in a variable:

```
Timestamp,6/22/2016 2:25:00 AM
mos,4.16
jitter,19.22
```

I want to split this variable and store the result in 3 different variables as follows:

```
Timestamp = 6/22/2016 2:25:00 AM
mos = 4.16
jitter = 19.22
```

Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
% set input "Timestamp,6/22/2016 2:25:00 AM
mos,4.16
jitter,19.22"
Timestamp,6/22/2016 2:25:00 AM
mos,4.16
jitter,19.22
% set lines [split $input \n]
{Timestamp,6/22/2016 2:25:00 AM} mos,4.16 jitter,19.22
% foreach line $lines {
    lassign [split $line ,] varname value
    set $varname $value
    set result($varname) $value
}
% set Timestamp
6/22/2016 2:25:00 AM
% set mos
4.16
% set jitter
19.22
% parray result
result(Timestamp) = 6/22/2016 2:25:00 AM
result(jitter)    = 19.22
result(mos)       = 4.16
```

Comment: I'd be more likely to use `regexp -inline {^([^,]+),(.*)$}` for the per-line splitting as that's more resistant to issues with commas in values, but otherwise it's the right approach. I also like putting the values in an array; it avoids _all sorts_ of surprises later.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, two variants on Dinesh's solution:

```
foreach item [split $input \n] {
    set value [lassign [regsub , $item { }] name]
    set result($name) $value
}
```

The main difference here is that it only (quasi-)splits on the first comma (the resulting string is treated as a regular whitespace-separated list with possibly more than two elements, hence the alternative invocation of `lassign`).

```
foreach {- name value} [regexp -line -inline -all {^([^,]+),(.*)$} $input] {
    set result($name) $value
}
```

This one demonstrates the regex splitting suggested by Donal.

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Answer (score -3):

```
     Timestamp,6/22/2016 2:25:00 AM
    mos,4.16
    jitter,19.22
    You can spit with (,) and you find an array . 
    then you retrieve the value of Index wise .
    As :- if variable name is var="6/22/2016 2:25:00 AM,4.16,19.22";  
    then   String[] val= var.split(",");
    val[0] = 6/22/2016 2:25:00 AM ;
    val[1] = 4.16;
    val[2] = 19.22;

if your technology is java .
```